# Angular app composed of angular app (modules)

Tags: angular, git, npm, module

I'm trying to figure out the best way to structure a (inevitably large) but currently small angular application that my team will be working on. This will be rewrite of a large legacy system which is a nightmare to maintain.

The main goal here is to keep the project lean, easy to navigate and modify from development point of view. I am currently thinking of something like:

```
- src
    - main app module
        - core application code & ui
        - feature modules
            - feature 1 module
            - feature 2 module
            - ..
```

This seems to make sense, however this will inevitably get large and messy. Folder structure is bound to get deep and hard to navigate. Confusion will probably ensue.

What I am thinking of doing instead is something like:

```
- src
    - main app module
    - core application code & ui
    - feature module dependencies

- feature 1 app
- feature 2 app
- ...
```

So each large feature will be its own angular application, which will be developed in isolation, re-using any shared/common code as modules. It can be ran and tested separately and once complete, it will be installed using

```
npm install https://github.com/<feature name>
```

into the main application. It will then be imported into the main application as a single component.

The problem that I'm having at the moment is trying to figure out:

- Is this a good idea?
- How to import angular applications into other angular applications as modules. This is mainly around the fact that each angular application starts with app.component.ts and app.module.ts, which results to name clashes when imported. The only way I can think of doing that is to wrap each feature module with a lightweight launcher 'app'. The app will be used to run and test it locally, which the module will be exported for other apps.

Has anyone faced this before?

Thanks!

Comment: You should take a look into nx. Seems to be exactly what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Nx seems exactly what I'm looking for. Will play around with it and see :) Link for anyone else that may be interested: https://github.com/nrwl/nx

Answer (score 1):

**Is this a good idea?**

If it's just you, then I recommend you keep it really simple. This has worked well for me in the past:

- Stable branch / Main master branch
- Feature branches (The branch upon which features are developed). When you're happy with those features then merge or rebase them back into the master branch - then you can delete the feature branch and move on to the next feature.

As far as angular apps and namespacing issues - I don't know enough to answer this.

Comment: Agreed, no reason to cut up the application.

Comment: I would definitely keep it simple if it was just me. This will be a team and most likely a number of teams as time goes by. The application is going to be a rewrite of a large legacy system which is a maintenance nightmare... What you advised is definitely a good idea and is our standard workflow of developing features :)